# Resizing an image to an exact pixel proportion without getting a squeezing distortion

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images

Here's the issue:

I'm trying to upload a drawing of mine onto Society6, they require the image to be specific proportions of 3300 px wide by 5100 px high. Each time I do this in Photoshop and constrain the proportions, it squeezes and distorts my image, making it skinnier and longer than before.

Does anyone have any advice on how to avoid the distortion while still having the exact size of image they require? I can't crop the image to be any less wide, so I'm feeling a little stuck.

Comment: What is the actual size / pixel dimensions of your drawing? As far as I understood you are trying to place your drawing into a mockup, define your problem more so that I can help you to resolve

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the Society6 Web site and saw a lot of images that do not conform to the dimensions you mention. It is possible that you are submitting an image for a specific category, say a phone case, which may require these dimensions. You will not get to the 33:51 aspect ratio unless your image is originally is in that ratio. Your choices are:

1. Crop a part of the image to 33:51 ratio and size it to fit 3300x5100 pixels
2. Create a canvas sized 3300x5100 pixels and place your image into that canvas. Then you can use the Transform tool on your image to fit it inside.
3. After the fitting, fill the canvas background with a suitable color and let it show as solid color framing your original
4. If you are extremely lucky and the image you have lends itself to that, you can try Content Aware Scale which will try to maintain the recognizable object proportions and scale the "empty" space between them.
5. Do not submit this image to Society6, find another suitable image.

Answer (score 1):

**First:**

You have to make sure your image is within the Society6 desired ratio. 
The distortion depends on the initial ratio of the image. To scale the image to **3300px/5100px** means the *original image* has to been in the scale ratio of approximately **0.6471***(Divide the Width by the Height and then Round off to about 4 decimal places)*.

> This means if your actual/initial width is maybe **800px**, the height
>   should be around **(800/0.6471)** which is approximately **1236px**. As long as
>   the initial scale is not within that ratio, then you have to crop the
>   image to scale before you transform it.

**Second:**

To Resize/Transform the Image, Open you ratio-scaled image with *Photoshop*
Navigate to the Image sizing through the *Image Menu* option through  **Image > Image Size >**

From the *Image Size dialog window* that show up,  Change the Width to **3300px** and make sure **Constrain to proportion** link is active(light shade of blue). That way the Height will automatically become **5100px** (Or close depending on the rounding off you made when cropping your original image).

**Summary:**
[image]

- I got a sample avatar **256px by 256px**(On the Right), with a ration of 1. With a width of 256px, the height has to be (256/0.647) = 395.6111px ~ **395.6px**.
- I then Created a new File and placed my image into it(On the Left) with (256px by 395.6px)
- Resizing the width to 3300px (Center) gives me a width approximately around 5100px. Thus a distortion less Scaling if you round off well.

**Note:** However like you notice, Croping will chop off some parts of the image or bring unecessary white space/empty pixels as you notice above. For that case you can do a content aware scale as +ACEkin advises, to get the main content of your drawing "in focus" before cropping.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be the exact same size and without distortions, well, not all of the photo will be able to appear, I mean, it may be cropped a bit on the edges. You start with Ctrl+T to transform. Hold Shift while you're resizing. When you're done you click enter, and make sure the images fills the whole artboard. Then you add the whole thing a clipping mask with the same size that they gave you. It's probably the only way. Cropping may work too.

Note: It should be 3300 px wide by 5100 high, which obviously means it will be a kinda HD portrait picture, so I think it's better to use a portrait picture instead of a landscape one.

I hope this helped :)